# Difference (angle) between two bearings

Tags: r, bearing, geosphere

Using `geosphere::bearing` I can calculate the bearing of two lines, but is it possible to calculate the angle between the two bearings ?

Of course you can try and subtract or sum up the bearings but in specific cases where one is negative and the other is positive this doesn't work.

For example if the `ber1` = - 175 and `ber2` = 175 the angle between should be 10.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Take the absolute difference (mod 360) between the angles and subtract it from 360 if it is greater than 180.

Comment: `abs(ber1) - abs(ber2) = 0`     -> subtracting 0 from 360 is equal to 360, the point I'm trying to make is that with implementing many conditions it might be possible to get the correct answer, but maybe there is a function that already has all these rules implemented

Comment: *If it is greater than 180*. And should be `abs(ber1 - ber2)`. If you're merely looking for an existing function then Google is your friend.

Comment: For a `C#` and `C` solution, see [Turn Direction for Target Heading](//stackoverflow.com/q/12869557).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure of a ready-made package but in case you are interested in a solution then you can try

```r
angle_diff <- function(theta1, theta2){
  theta <- abs(theta1 - theta2) %% 360 
  return(ifelse(theta > 180, 360 - theta, theta))
  }
```

which gives the angle between your example bearings -175 & 175 as

```
angle_diff(-175, 175)
#[1] 10
```

Comment: `180 - abs(180 - abs(theta1 - theta2) %% 360)` also works

Comment: may I ask why do you use the `%%` operator ?

Comment: @adl without it the result for e.g. (-175, 175) would be negative

Comment: @adl `%%` (modulo) is used here to calculate the remainder so that it brings down theta to less than 360. You can consider an example `angle_diff(450, 45)` to understand the calculation